# In Gulp 4 should I now use .series() instead of .pipe()?

Tags: gulp, gulp-4

In gulp version 4 should I now use `series()` instead of `pipe()`? For example; my v3 task is below, should I change it to the last bit of code I've pasted? Is that the new gulp v4 way of doing things?

```
gulp.task('mytask', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'scripts/a.js',
        'scripts/b.js',
        'scripts/c.js',
    ])
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./scripts'))
        .pipe(rename('all.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./scripts'));
});
```

New v4 way???

```
gulp.task('mytask', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'scripts/a.js',
        'scripts/b.js',
        'scripts/c.js',
    ])
        .series(
            concat('all.js'), 
            gulp.dest('./scripts'), 
            rename('all.min.js'), 
            uglify(), 
            gulp.dest('./scripts')
        );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In Gulp 4, `series` is used to run *multiple* tasks one after another, whereas `pipe` is used to transform a stream within a *single* task.

So you would change your task code to look like the following. The updated code returns a stream made with `src` and `pipe`d through some transformations.

```
exports.mytask = function() {
    return gulp.src([
            'scripts/a.js',
            'scripts/b.js',
            'scripts/c.js',
        ])
        .pipe(concat('all.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./scripts'))
        .pipe(rename('all.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./scripts'));
});
```

There are various ways you can make functions that are tasks. See the [docs here](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion#returning-a-stream) for more information.

Once you've got several tasks created you can compose them with `series` or `parallel`. See [here](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/creating-tasks#compose-tasks) for more information on composing multiple tasks together.

```
exports.mytask1 = ...
exports.mytask2 = ...

exports.alltasks = gulp.series(
    mytask1,
    mytask2
);
```

Comment: Could be just `exports.alltasks = gulp.series(mytask1, mytask2);`  No need for the `function()` stuff.

Comment: Good point! Updated.

Comment: You don't need the `return` either.